# Pseudo element has excessive margins

Tags: html, css, margin, pseudo-element

In the following snippet, a square pseudo-element is transformed.

However, I don't understand where the spacing between the `<div>` and the `<p>` after it come from.

```css
.shape::after {
  --side1-em: 10;
  --side2-em: 5;
  --alpha-deg: 30;
  --sin-alpha: 0.5;
  --offset-deg: 100;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: calc(1em * var(--side1-em));
  height: calc(1em * var(--side1-em));
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(calc(-90deg + var(--offset-deg) * 1deg))
             skew(calc((90 - var(--alpha-deg)) * 1deg))
             scaleY(calc(var(--sin-alpha) * (var(--side2-em) / var(--side1-em))));
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="trigonometry">
  <div class="shape"></div>
</div>
<p>hello world</p>
```

From chrome dev tools I see this content for the `<div class="shape">` element
[image]
and these margins for the `::after` pseudo-element
[image]
which you can see, protrudes beyond the content shown in the previous screenshot. However, setting `margin: 0;` doesn't seem to fix the issue. Furthermore, when `::after` is selected in the dev tools, I can't see any `margin: whatever;` in the *Styles* nor in the *Computer* tab.

---

When I posted this question, I was erroneously thinking that the margin subject of the question was the reason for the vertical spacing between the black transformed square and the text below. Now I realize that spacing is simply due to what the square looks like *before* the `transform`.

Comment: this is the default behavior of block element

Comment: @TemaniAfif, honestly I've read those answers (yours and the other one) a few times but I still don't get it. Maybe I'll understand at some point. For the time being, is there anything I can do with CSS to remove all that margin?

Comment: use inline-block instead of block